# href a div inside a navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using a template from bootstrap. [This is the navigation bar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/album/) and you can see the about section inside it. In my case there is a bootstrap button inside:

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Light</button>`

On pressing the button the navigation bar is expected to open by sliding down revealing the about section.

I've done everything with CSS that I know of like using `href`. I think this has to do with Javascript part of bootstrap, the `.onclick` function or something like that.

please help.

Comment: Post the code you've attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the div containing the about part of the navbar, give it `class="collapse"`, and an id, for example `id="navbarHeader"`.

For the button add, `data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarHeader"`

Make sure that you have imported the javascript imports from bootstrap (as well as the styles):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-gjdwi9) for referance (a copy of the album page you linked to).

```
    <header>
      <div class="collapse bg-dark" id="navbarHeader">
        <div class="container" style="height:200px">
          <!-- add your hidden content (expands to the height of this content-->
          <!-- if no content, then nothing to expand, i added style="height:200px", but this can be removed -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container">
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center">
            <!-- your brand text/image -->
          </a>
          <!-- The menu button -->
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarHeader">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: thank you so much. that was so easy, I literally spent like 1 day googling it.